# Libraries causing JavaFX application to crash shortly after launch

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, javafx

I've spend  the last couple weeks making a JavaFX application which I would like to export to a runnable jar.  I have absolutely no problems playing the game in eclipse.  When I export the application, I have three different options of library handling.  "Extract required libraries into generated JAR", "Package required libraries into generated JAR" and "Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated jar".

When the first radio button is checked (Extract), the app runs no problem.

[image]

However when the second radio button is checked (Package), the app runs for about 5 seconds, then crashes upon loading.

I need to "Package required libraries into generated JAR" in order to port this app to Android.  If I do not package the libraries, the app will not work.

Why is this issue occurring?  I am running and compiling the latest version of Java (1.8).  This makes no sense to me.

After commenting out some code, I found what lines were causing an error,

```
private static Group root;

public Screen(Group root) {
    this.root = root;
    root.getChildren().add(stats.getGroup());
    root.getChildren().add(help.getGroup());
    root.getChildren().add(options.getGroup());
    root.getChildren().add(highScores.getGroup());
    root.getChildren().add(playGame.getGroup());
    root.getChildren().add(mainMenu.getGroup());

}
```

I condensed the code, but you get the point.  Why is this occurring? This is unlike any Java issue I have had in the past.

Thanks in advance,

-Steve

Comment: If you want to port your JavaFX app to Android, it would seem that you should be using some variation of the [javafx ports sample build script](http://javafxports.org/page/Getting_Started) and not whatever packager is built into Eclipse.

Comment: I use the build scripts, I have ported a few test applications before and have had no problems.  If I do not package the libraries, all that shows up on my Android is a black screen.

Comment: The issue is not porting it, the issue is the .jar is crashing when I package the libraries as opposed to extracting the libraries.  The .jar crashes on windows, linux and Android.

Comment: Please update your question to include the the names of the jar files for the libraries you are trying to package and to include the source of the build scripts you are using.   Are you using [e(fx)clipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial1)?  Please confirm that your libraries are only Java code and do not load native libraries.  On what system and environment is the .jar crashing?  There are other utilities which can package Java apps in one jar (e.g. [onejar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net)).

Comment: The [javafxports wiki guide to building and deploying](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/wiki/Building%20and%20deploying%20JavaFX%20Applications) explains that: "JFX_APP points to dist directory of your regular javafx application. (where all application jars sit)". So it seems that the process takes as input multiple jar files and does not require a pre-processing step in Eclipse or another tool to place all of the application class files in a single jar.

Comment: You are referring to the gradle createProject?
-PJFX_APP=/home/user/NetBeansProjects/HelloAndroidWorld/dist

the /dist/ directory contains the latest compiled .jar if I am not mistaking.  Since I use eclipse, I don't have a /dist/ in my workspace.  Therefore I expored my own .jar in eclipse

Comment: If there is another method of porting, I am all for using that.  But following the samples listed on the website you linked to.  It seems like my issue is NOT with the port.

Comment: My .jar crashes in windows, that is my issue.  It only crashes when I "package libraries" and not "extract libraries" and I don't understand why/how to fix that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69358/discussion-between-steven-and-jewelsea).

Comment: I don't know how to fix your issue either, but if include enough information in your question that somebody can replicate your issue, it might help somebody to diagnose the problem and provide an answer.